# jom hangs while building on Qt Creator - MSVC 2008 Express

Tags: qt, visual-c++, build, makefile, qt-creator

I have a Qt project that I've been working on for months, and for no apparent reason it stopped building this afternoon. Running qmake doesn't help, and when this happened last time, the only way I managed to get it back to working state was to reinstall Qt and MSVC 2008 Express. I would like to find out what's going on instead.

This is all I see when I start building:

> 20:19:22: Running build steps for project ProjectName...
>
> 20:19:22: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>
> 20:19:22: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"

If I try to clean the project, the same thing happens (since jom.exe also drives the project clean). I have no clue what's going on and would appreciate any hints.

**Update:** Not so urgent anymore, because deleting the build folder altogether makes things work again. But if anyone can pitch in with the jom.exe conundrum (why does it stall instead of exiting?), that would help. Leaving the question up in case it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me too, downloaded the latest executable and copied in the qtsdk folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be related to [this](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-6805) bug. For me, upgrading to the last version of [jom](ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/jom/) resolved the issue.